# If $\lim _{ n\to\infty } \sqrt [ n ]{ \sum _{ i=0 }^{ k } a_i ^n } =\max { \{{ a }_{ 1 }, \ldots ,{ a }_{ k }\} } $ then $\min=?$

Tags: analysis

If $\lim _{ n\to\infty } \sqrt [ n ]{ \sum _{ i=0 }^{ k } a_i ^n } =\max { \{{ a }_{ 1 }, \ldots ,{ a }_{ k }\} } $ then what is the equivalent for $\min$?

Comment: Can we assume that $a_i > 0$ for each $i$?

Comment: Your equation may not hold, as the limit may not even exist. For example, if $k=1$ and $a_1=-1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : because of your question I realised $a_i$ can be 0, negative, complex or even matrix thanks, that generalises the concept of Max

Comment: @5xum : that is fantastic, k being negative and idea of what is max of a number, thanks

Comment: @Arjang I never said $k$ is negative....

Comment: @5xum : but you gave me the idea, wonder if I can swap sum with integration to see where it leads.

Comment: @Arjang in fact, we indeed find that for a sufficiently nice function $a:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$, we have 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\int_0^1 [a(x)]^n\,dx \right]^{1/n} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}a(x)
$$
you may find [$L^p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) to be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each $a_i > 0$, we could compute
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\sum_{i=0}^k a_i^{-n}\right]^{-1/n} = \min\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k\}
$$

Comment: fantastic, without the assumption it generalises the notion of minimum for complex numbers and even matrices.

Comment: I would hesitate to apply this to matrices; we would need to assume that the $a_i$ are invertible.  Also, $n$th roots are a terrible pain without a lot many assumptions

Comment: intresting that max does not require invertibility